# Getting a weird Android error in my R class

Tags: java, android

I can't export my project to make an apk because of an error in my gen->com.example.project->R.java class. Here's the snippet of code where the error lies in:

```
public static final class drawable {
        public static final int 512=0x7f020000;
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020001;
        public static final int mr_excuse=0x7f020002;
    }
```

The very first line, the 512, that is where the error is. I have no idea where that 512 comes from. I tried editing the file and deleting that entire line, but when I try to save it I get a message saying:

```
[2014-02-23 10:45:02 - MrExcuse] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
```

I have no idea what this message is for. I just want to remove the error.

Comment: Do you have anything with `512` in file name in any res/drawable folder? Invalid file names should have been picked up by aapt and reported as errors, but as it's software written by humans, there can be bugs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you've tried to define a resource with an ID of 512. You can't do that - it's not a valid identifier.

Look at the piece of your XML where you've defined `ic_launcher` and `mr_excuse`, and look for `512` near that... then give it a proper name.

Comment: Yes that is what it was. You answered it first.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I checked my drawable file paths and deleted a picture called 512. It solved the problem.

Comment: as I was writing this, no answers were made yet. After uploading my answer, I saw that Jon Skeet beat me to it. He get's the points.